# Pass data between applications in Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat7, cross-application

We have several applications deployed in Tomcat and want to add 1 application to handle authentication for all of the other applications.

All applications are defined as different host elements in Tomcat configuration (server.xml) like following example:

```
<Host name="loginapp.localhost" appBase="loginapp" />

<Host name="webapp1.localhost" appBase="webapp1" />
<Host name="webapp2.localhost" appBase="webapp2" />
...
```

What is a best practice to accomplish this?

How I see things are going to work and what I have tried so far:

When a user goes to an url that points to webapp1, a request filter in the application sees that the user has not been authenticated yet and redirects to the "loginapp" where authentication happens and redirects back to webapp1 where the user now has been authenticated for (only for this specific application).

What I need is to share data between these applications. And I've found it should be possible to share session attributes across applications like following (example I've found):

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("sharedId", shared);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/URLofOtherServlet").forward(request, response);
```

But I'm not sure how I can achieve this as my applications are running inside the same Tomcat server, but are accessed by different domain names. Is this even possible this way? Or are there other options for my case?

---

EDIT:

Apparently my "solution" above is only possible for use inside one application.

What I have found now while researching further is JNDI resources. Would this be something I can use to share some data between my applications?

Comment: I don't have any solution for your issue, but I still have to say that `getRequestDispatcher` should be used only within the same Webapp, as it adds the context root of your web application to the URL (as far as I know).

Comment: What you're describing is single sign on (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On) but I think that applies to applications within the same host element, not across multiple hosts.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock Maybe wasn't very clear, but I don't want the user to be authenticated for all applications after authenticating, but only for this single application where the original request pointed to.

Comment: @Ephi Yeah, so I guess that's no solution for me then, thanks.

Comment: Why don't use a CAS system? Here some points: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home